# What to use in lieu of NSOutlineViewDataSource outlineView:draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:?

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsoutlineview

Unlike `NSTableViewDataSource`, the `NSOutlineViewDataSource` protocol has no `outlineView:draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:` selector.  When a user drags an item from my `NSOutlineView`, how do I detect when the item has been dropped?

I tried implementing `draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:` in my datasource/delegate, but it never gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSOutlineViewDataSource` *does* define the `outlineView:draggingSession:endedAtPoint:operation:` method, you can see it if you look at the header. I have no idea why it's not in the docs.

To see the header, choose **File > Open Quickly** in Xcode and type `NSOutlineView`.

The method is only available as of 10.7.

Comment: Wow... so much for the docs.  I thought they were generated from the headers a la Javadoc.

Comment: I think normally they are. No idea why that process seems to have failed with this class.